# Liquibase - Trim whitespaces from CSV

Tags: csv, liquibase

I have a formatted CSV file for `<loadData .../>` of **Liquibase**.
There are some whitespaces for having a nice look.
But because of that whitespaces, I have wrong data in my DB.

How to solve it? Is there any "flag" or something for forcing **Liquibase** to trim whitespaces?

I tried to make it looking something like the next

```
id;name   ;surname
1 ;test123;test123
2 ;test1  ;test123
3 ;"test" ;test123
```

Anyway, my DB contains `test1__` and `test"_` as well where `_` is a space.

Also `quotchar="&quot;"` didn't help (and it was expected, it is a redundant line).

Btw, id column which is defined as numeric - ok (1,2,3, etc with no errors).

Answer (score 2):

Check out this [Jira issue](https://liquibase.jira.com/browse/CORE-2743).

To quote Nathan Voxland:

> It probably makes sense to keep the default as trimming since I think
>   that will cause less surprises. However, I added a global
>   configuration flag that lets you change the default.
>
> You can set it either through a liquibase.trimCsvWhitespace=false
>   system property or by using the
>   LiquibaseConfiguration.getInstance().getProperty(GlobalConfiguration.class,
>   GlobalConfiguration.CSV_TRIM_WHITESPACE).setValue() API call.

Try adding `liquibase.trimCsvWhitespace=false`property.

> On further review, it looks like it was a change just in 3.5.0. I
>   usually try to keep backwards compatibility, even when it is
>   unexpected behavior but was thinking it had changed with 3.4.0 and so
>   changing it back to preserving whitespace would break other people
>   that are now expecting it to be trimming.
>
> However, since it did change unexpectedly in 3.5.0 only, it is
>   definitely a bug and so I'm just setting the logic back to preserving
>   whitespace.

Accodring to Jira ticket this bug was fixed in liquibase version `3.5.1`, but looks like it actually wasn't.

Comment: could you please advise me where should I put `liquibase.trimCsvWhitespace=false` to?

Comment: Put it in your `application.properties` file. It should work if your `liquibase` version is old enough.

Comment: thx, I've got the expected result neither with `liquibase.trimCsvWhitespace=false` or `true`. My Liquibase is `3.5.5`. Probably, I'll try to use Flyway

Comment: As the [latest comment](https://liquibase.jira.com/browse/CORE-2743?focusedCommentId=43697) on the linked issue insinuates, it looks like the property was just silently removed in more recent versions (had no effect for me either with 3.10.3).